# Split and horizontal merge data-frame into single field in R

Tags: r, merge, split, dplyr

I'd like to merge two dataframes.

One dataframe is a list of routes:

```
code   d   p
 AMM PFO   3
 AMM BER   3
 AMM SVQ   3
```

the other dataframe is a list of cities:

```
code  cityname  country
TYO   Tokyo     Japan
```

I'd like to merge by=code

to end up with something like this: (d,p)

```
code  city      country r1      r2
PIS   Poitiers  France  LON,14  LYS,65
```

But I'm not sure how I can split it up. For my use case I don't need column names but I need each route to be in a different column

Is this possible in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work with any number of routes for any number of departure and destination cities.

It combines the `p` and `d` columns, and the joins with the destination city info. The only tricky part is to assign arbitrary route numbers, which it does with the `min_rank()` call.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# slightly expanded data set to make sure it works with multiple departure cities
d1 <- data.frame(
  code = c(rep("AMM", 3), "TYO"),
  d = c("PFO", "BER", "SVQ", "PFO"),
  p = c(3, 3, 7, 4)
)

d2 <- data.frame(
  code = c("AMM", "TYO"), 
  cityname = c("Zizya", "Tokyo"), 
  country = c("Jordan", "Japan")
)

d1 %>% 
  unite(dp, d, p, sep = ",") %>%
  left_join(d2, by = "code") %>%
  group_by(code) %>%
  mutate(route = min_rank(dp)) %>%
  mutate(route = paste0("r", route)) %>%
  spread(route, dp)
```

Comment: this actually works pretty well!

`library(gtools)`

`d1 <- subset(d1,d1$cityname != 'N/A')`
`d1 <- d1[mixedorder(colnames(d1))]`
`d1 <- Filter(function(x)!all(is.na(x)), d1)`

I had to add a few things to sort the list and remove N/As. But it turned out perfectly in the end

Comment: Ah, thanks @jaksco. I'll check out the gtools package.